# Set quality for PNG images in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a matlab code and it generates a .png image of 1024*768 resolution. The images are about 450KB in size and I need to know how to optimise and compress these images using matlab.
Can't I play with the quality as in JPEG ? 
I read the imwrite manual and don`t seem to find a good way to do this.
Is there any way to achieve it in matlab ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By design PNG files are lossless - there is no 'quality' to be adjusted (it's probably why a mod changed your question title).

You can reduce the number of colors in the image (the color depth) which will in turn reduce filesize (PNG-8 instead of PNG-24, for example), but the whole point of PNG is it produces **lossless** images, so there is simple no quality value a la JPEG.

Comment: See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Compression, and the comments to one of the answers below

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the manual :

A parameter of input in case it is JPEG:

```
'Quality' - A number between 0 and 100; higher numbers mean higher quality (less image   degradation due to compression), but the resulting file size is larger.
```

> > imwrite(x,'c:\1.jpg','Quality',10)

edit: Sorry, I answered this one while the title was JPEG and not PNG.

Comment: thnx but I am looking for .png files.

Comment: @Momo - you'd better change the title of your question then, as it says JPEG!

Answer (score 0):

PNG doesn't support any quality settings - it is a lossless format. The compression it applies is generally as good as possible.

Comment: I alsow thought like that, but then I saw : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Compression

Comment: @Andrey - interesting link, thanks. So there are different degrees of compression possible but it's not user selectable, it just depends on the sophistication of the encoder.

Comment: Exactly... But it was really surprising for me as well.

Comment: Hi , thanks for all answers. Let us say that Matlab produces the best png quality. Is there any way to make it to produce the least optimised quality ?